# do applications made for ios use a virtual machine?

Tags: ios

In java when we make applications java uses an virtual machine to run those applications in different computers, and i'm wonderinng if swift or objective-c  does the same.
and in case of that i would like to know the name of that virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

No, both Objective-C and Swift compile to native machine code that runs directly on the hardware, without a virtual machine. Code compiled for one platform will not work on the other — unlike Java's bytecode, native code requires recompilation for all different platforms.

[Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a superset of C (which is a language which compiles to machine code) that has a rich [runtime library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective_c_runtime?language=occ) while Swift is its own language but is still ["compiled and optimized to get the most out of modern hardware"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0).